# Adding a directory path under IntelliJ 12 claims Library 'LibraryName' is not used and has no effect

Tags: intellij-idea, codenameone, intellij-plugin

I maintain an IntelliJ plugin (Codename one) and we need to control the users classpath. I'm adding a classpath either via the plugin or manually by going to here:

[image]

And pressing the + sign where I pick Java:

[image]

Then choose classes:

[image]

This seems to work OK:

[image]

But the completion and other such functionality doesn't work and when I go back the entry is disabled and I get this error message:

[image]

This doesn't really tell me anything?

A workaround is to open the .iml file in a text editor, and add the following to the orderEntry list:

```
<orderEntry type="library" scope="PROVIDED" name="LibraryName" level="project" />
```

Unfortunately this isn't very practical and it only solves some of the problems I'm experiencing. Any direction or hint would be appreciated here.

**Edit**: Adding screenshot of preferences UI:

[image]

**Second Edit**: Screenshot of the module section

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This doesn't really tell me anything?

IntelliJ is trying to warn you that you have created a library, but it is not referenced anywhere in the project. It is gently asking "Did you mean to add this library as a dependency?".

The entry is not disabled. It is greyed out to show that it is not referenced in any module as a dependency. Once you add the library to the dependencies list, the color will change.

It is a two-step process:

1. Create a library
2. Reference new library in a module

Code completion is not working because your module is not aware of the library classes.

**Module dependencies**

[image]

**Non-referenced and referenced libraries**

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately I don't see where the dependency option is? 
Is it possible it was disabled by our plugin inadvertently?

Comment: It should be in module preferences. Check dependencies tab.

Comment: I feel a bit stupid but I can't see it there. I edited my answer with a screenshot of the preferences dialog. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @ShaiAlmog: Added screenshots. Let me know if you still have difficulties finding it. It is under Project Structure(⌘;)

Comment: Thanks, I attached a screenshot of how it looks on our plugin. I guess our developer disabled that but I'm not sure what he did to trigger that. If I add a regular Java module I see what you see. I'm accepting your answer but if you have a pointer to where this is defined in the plugin it would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: @ShaiAlmog: It looks like custom module. Look for any classes implementing com.intellij.openapi.module.Module interface as a starting point. Or any reference of the word "module". The implementation class also can be referenced in META-INF/plugin.xml

Answer (score 2):

The answer from kukido is good, for additional details though check out this: http://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5509300

Essentially what I want is to still have my module but add a dependency programmatically which can be done by:

```
ModifiableRootModel model = ModuleRootManager.getInstance(module).getModifiableModel();
model.addLibraryEntry(library);
model.commit();
```